# How to make bookmark list for a recyclerview?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recyclerview that get data from database in my host. i want to put a button in each post which can add that post to favorite list(a recyclerview in another activity). i code these but that doesn't work and just show me force close. in fact i'm confused what is wrong. anyone can help please?
this is my MainActivity code that shows posts in it :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupRecyclerView();
        getPostsFromDatabase();

        ApiService apiService = new ApiService(this);

        apiService.getPosts(new ApiService.OnPostsRecieved() {
            @Override
            public void onRecieved(List<Post> posts) {

                PostDatabseOpenHelper openHelper = new PostDatabseOpenHelper(MainActivity.this);
                openHelper.addPosts(posts);


                PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(MainActivity.this, posts);


                recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

            }
        });
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);}

    private void getPostsFromDatabase() {
        PostDatabseOpenHelper databseOpenHelper = new PostDatabseOpenHelper(this);
        List<Post> posts = databseOpenHelper.getPosts();
        PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, posts);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
    }
}
```

this is databaseOpenHelper codes:

```
public class PostDatabseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String COL_ID="col_id";
    public static final String COL_CONTENT="col_content";
    public static final String COL_IS_FAV="col_is_fav";


    private static final String SQL_COMMAND_CREATE_POST_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+POST_TABLE_NAME+"("+
            COL_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            COL_CONTENT+" TEXT,"+
            COL_IS_FAV+"INTEGER DEFAULT 0);";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(SQL_COMMAND_CREATE_POST_TABLE);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+e.toString() );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public boolean addPost(Post post){
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_ID,post.getId());
        cv.put(COL_CONTENT,post.getContent());
        cv.put(COL_IS_FAV,post.getIsFav());


        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        long isInserted=sqLiteDatabase.insert(POST_TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        Log.i(TAG, "addPost: "+isInserted);
        if (isInserted>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts(){
        List<Post>posts=new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase =this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+POST_TABLE_NAME,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                Post post=new Post();
                post.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                post.setContent(cursor.getString(1));
                post.setIsFav(cursor.getInt(2));

                posts.add(post);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        sqliteDatabase.close();
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPostIsFav(int postId,int isFav){
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_IS_FAV,isFav);
        int rowAffected=sqliteDatabase.update(POST_TABLE_NAME,contentValues,COL_ID+" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(postId)});
        sqliteDatabase.close();
    }
}
```

here is Adapter codes:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostviewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Post> posts;

    @Override
    public PostviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_post,parent,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostviewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Post post=posts.get(position);
        holder.content.setText(post.getContent());

        holder.content.setText(posts.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getContent());
    }

    public void btnFavClicked(View view){
        PostDatabseOpenHelper helper=new PostDatabseOpenHelper(context);
        helper.setPostIsFav(0,1);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }
}
```

and this is Favorite.class codes:

```
public class Favorite extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);

        setupRecyclerView();
        getPostsFromDatabase();

        ApiService apiService = new ApiService(this);

        apiService.getPosts(new ApiService.OnPostsRecieved() {
            @Override
            public void onRecieved(List<Post> posts) {

                PostDatabseOpenHelper openHelper = new PostDatabseOpenHelper(Favorite.this);

                TextView contentTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Postcontent);

                PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(Favorite.this, posts);


                recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);}}); 
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager); 
    }


    private void getPostsFromDatabase() {
        PostDatabseOpenHelper databseOpenHelper = new PostDatabseOpenHelper(this);
        List<Post> posts = databseOpenHelper.getPosts();
        PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, posts);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
    }
}
```

and this is my logcat when it crashes :

```
09-02 14:00:09.617 20392-20392/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:169)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                       at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
                                                       at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:574)
                                                       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:169) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

Comment: If it crashes, please check logcat for the error and also include it here

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Done! check it out

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `post.setIsFav(cursor.getInt(2));` and see what the cursor holds in the debug console.